# Using find_or_create_by! in before_action filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a weird behaviour when using `User.find_or_create_by!` in `before_action` filter as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API

before_action :authorize_request

attr_reader :current_user

  private

  def authorize_request
    @current_user = (AuthorizeApiRequest.new(request.headers).call)[:user]
  end
end
```

Then in `AuthorizeApiRequest` I'm checking for existence or creating a new User by name:

```
class AuthorizeApiRequest
  def initialize(headers = {})
    @headers = headers
  end

  def call
    {
      user: user
    }
  end

def user
    if decoded_auth_token && decoded_auth_token[:sub]
      @user ||= User.find_or_create_by!(username: decoded_auth_token[:sub])
      Rails.logger.silence do
        @user.update_column(:token, http_auth_header)
      end
      @user
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
    raise(
      ExceptionHandler::InvalidToken,
      ("#{Message.invalid_token} #{e.message}")
    )
  end
end
```

Example of UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def me
    if user_info_service.call
      json_response current_user, :ok, include: 'shop'
    else
      raise AuthenticationError
    end
  end

  private

  def user_info_service_class
    @user_info_service_class ||= ServiceProvider.get(:user_info_service)
  end

  def user_info_service
    @user_info_service ||= user_info_service_class.new(user: current_user)
  end
end
```

What is **weird** is that sometimes the User is created twice with the same username, sometimes not.
I'm using Ember JS in the front and another call is made to `shops` right after the authentication with JWT. All the routes are protected. I have the impression that calling `current_user` is not always in the same thread or sth like that and it results in having 2 identical users:
- the first one with just a username attribute set
- another one with all the others User attributes.

Here is the `User` model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, on: :create
  validates :shop_identifier, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }, on: :update
  validates :first_name, presence: true, on: :update
  validates :last_name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, scope: :first_name }, on: :update

  before_update do |user|
    user.first_name = first_name.strip.capitalize
    user.last_name = last_name.strip.upcase

end
```

Any ideas ? Thank you

Comment: It seems like it is a known issue, - Rails docs [tell](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) about it: `Please note *this method is not atomic*, it runs first a SELECT, and if there are no results an INSERT is attempted. If there are other threads or processes there is a race condition between both calls and it could be the case that you end up with two similar records.`

Comment: The idea is to find or create a User by its `username`, then make another request (_unfortunately it is provided by another external service_) to update the found/created User. What is happening is that 2 controllers are hit in the same time: `shops` and `users`, both triggering the `before_action` filter creating the same user. Still no clues ?